# The meaning of アツい

Tags: slang, japanese-to-english

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMIG3he9L3g

In the beginning of this video 花澤香菜さん says

> この漫画がアツい！

For あつい the meanings I'm aware of are
暑い hot (weather), 熱い hot (object), 厚い (thick)

Is this アツい meant to be some kind of slang to mean 'cool', or 'a hot topic'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's "hot" as in "hot topic", and this shouldn't be difficult for an English speaker. On the other hand, we never say 寒い/涼しい to mean "cool" as a compliment for a manga (寒い漫画 means "unfunny manga"). While クールな is understood by young people through music promotion or English classes, not many people use it themselves.